# Azure Private Endpoint - The resource type 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts' is not a supported resource type

Tags: azure, azure-storage

When trying to configure a Private Endpoint on a storage account, I get an empty list of resource types

[image]

And if I try to do it with the resource id instead, I get the following error

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment works fine successfully.***

This issue may occur if your region is mismatched it will not show your resource type. To resolve issue check whether while create a storage account you can able to create a private endpoint as below.

[image]

Thus, my private endpoint is created successfully as below.

[image]

Suppose, if you are already created a storage account you want to configure private endpoint make use of below workarounds.

***In your storage account -> click networking under security and networking ->private endpoint connection ->Add private endpoint as below.***

[image]

While adding a new private endpoint ***in a storage account your resource type and resource are automatically recognize and display as below.*** This way helps you in order to prevent a resource unsupported issue.

[image]